# Where are these dots coming from? How to get rid of them?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, ide

For the life of me, I don't know when and how these "dots" started showing up in my IDE. I'm not sure if it's Visual Studio OR Code Rush from DevExpress that is doing it.

[image]

If anyone knows how to make them go away, please help! =)

Comment: somehow, you turned on the "show white space" option

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those dots represent space characters.  You will also see little arrows for tabs, and little hooked arrows for carriage returns.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to toggle the dots you're seeing.

BTW this is a standard Visual Studio feature.  It has nothing to do with CodeRush or any other plugin.

**EDIT** As Martin points out, you could press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.  Personally I press CTRL then hold it down for the R & W keystrokes.  It's less typing.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! One day they just appeared! I must have smacked some additional keys at one time or another! Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.  I use that shortcut on occasion to see whether a file is filled with tabs or spaces.  I can imagine they'd be pretty annoying if they were visible all the time :)